# Function returning false negative

Tags: php

I am saving the gamestate from a mobile game on a MySql database. The information is successfully saved, however it is echoing that there was an error in saving the game state. I'm still adjusting to php and not sure where this is coming from.

PS I know the SQL statement is insecure. Right now I'm just getting the fundamentals up and running as the statements and tables themselves will change soon.

Listining for incoming json:

```
    } else if ($tag == 'save_game_state') {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $virtumon = $_POST['monster'];
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
    $exp = $_POST['exp'];
    $user = $db->saveGameState($email, $monster, $qty, $exp);
        if ($user) {
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["The game state has been successfully saved"];
         echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user failed to store
            $response["error"] = 1;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in saving the game state";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
```

Inputting the information into the DB and returning success/failure.

```
    public function saveGameState($email, $monster, $qty, $exp) {

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_profiles(email, monster, qty, exp) VALUES('$email', '$monster', '$qty', '$exp')") or die(mysql_error());
    // TODO check for successful store
    $success = mysql_query("SELECT email, monster, qty, exp FROM user_profiles WHERE email = '$email' AND monster= '$monster' AND qty = '$qty' AND exp = '$exp'");
   if ($success) {
            return mysql_fetch_array($success);
    } else {
       return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: @DanielA.White PLEASE READ THE WHOLE POST "PS I know the SQL statement is insecure. Right now I'm just getting the fundamentals up and running as the statements and tables themselves will change soon."!!!

Comment: @DanielA.White: KDEx mentioned that he is aware of that already...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely shouldn't run a `SELECT` after your `INSERT` to check and see if it worked.  Just check what `$result` is after it's ran.  From

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php :

> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error

Try

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_profiles(email, monster, qty, exp) VALUES('$email', '$monster', '$qty', '$exp')") or die(mysql_error());
return $result;
```

If you want to return the contents of what you just inserted then call another function after you run `saveGameState`.  Though, if you already have the values you can just use those instead of querying the database again.

You should also look into the use of [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php).

Comment: Yeah, that is probably a better idea. They could also use `return mysql_affected_rows() > 0;` as well.

Comment: @aldo that would not even be needed since he's doing an `INSERT`.  You're just having to call another function when the return of the original `mysql_query` is telling him whether it was successful or not.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking whether or not your select statement was successful. You should be checking whether or not the insert was successful.

```
if ($result = mysql_query(INSERT INTO user_profiles(email, monster, qty, exp) VALUES('$email', '$monster', '$qty', '$exp') or die(mysql_error())) {
    if ($success = mysql_query("SELECT email, monster, qty, exp FROM user_profiles WHERE email = '$email' AND monster= '$monster' AND qty = '$qty' AND exp = '$exp'") or die(mysql_error())) {
        if (mysql_num_rows($success) > 0) return mysql_fetch_assoc($success);
    }
}
else { return false; }
```